# Generating Component SEF URLs in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-sef-urls

I have a custom Joomla component and a router for building my SEF URL's for use within the site, and everything is usually shiny - internally, all of my links look and act fantastic.

I recently route a controller action that sends a list of links through email, and I've noticed that my URLs are coming out.... funky - hopefully someone can tell me why.

Usually, my router generates an internal link that looks like this:

```
http://localhost/Registry/calendar/265889635/Some-Long-Boring-Event
```

However, when I send an email and preparing the same URL through the same router I get:

```
http://localhost/Registry/Registry/component/calendar/569555803/Some-Long-Boring-Event
```

Has anybody run into this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `Itemid` GET parameter in the URL.  My guess is that it's not set in the url used in emails...

Answer (score 0):

I would turn off SEF URLs temporarily and get the non-SEF version of the link you want.  Compare that will the URL you are using and see what is different/missing.